# Scraping with BeautifulSoup showing too many rows

Tags: python, html, css, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Thank you for your help in advance! I'm a beginner at this stuff so any help is appreciated. If there is a helpful guide to using beautifulsoup to do this, I'll take a link. Haven't been able to make it work.

I would like to scrape [this page](https://www.wine.com/product/shafer-red-shoulder-ranch-chardonnay-2014/154926) for wineRatings_initials and wineRatings_rating and averageRating_average and averageRating_number from ul.wineRatings_list, span.pipSecContent_copy, and latitude/longitude from href link under figure.pipWineryImage_map (38.417216 / -122.336862)

This brings back all instances of wineRatings_initials, even those under div.prodPedigree, which I don't need.
soup.find_all("span", {"class": "wineRatings_initials"})

```
 import urllib2 from bs4 
 import BeautifulSoup wine_page = 'wine.com/product/shafer-red-shoulder-ranch-chardonnay-2014/‌​…; 
 page = urllib2.urlopen(wine_page) 
 soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser') 
 soup.find_all(class_='wineRatings_initials')
```

Comment: sorry - here is code:
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
wine_page = 'https://www.wine.com/product/shafer-red-shoulder-ranch-chardonnay-2014/154926'
page = urllib2.urlopen(wine_page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
soup.find_all(class_='wineRatings_initials')

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free programming service, nor will we Google for you. Beautifulsoup is a clear, easy and well documented library with plenty of tutorials teaching you how to use it. I would suggest that you find a tutorial, read through some other questions on this site for beuatifulsoup which will help you learn some best practices and then ask a question if you get stuck, giving a clear definition of what your problem is and how we can help you, not spouting out demands and refusing to put in effort.

Comment: @EthanField - I did not mean to use it as a programming service, although I can see how my question comes off that way. It was not a demand. I guess I'll go back to the tutorials!

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused about your question, but if I understand right, you want to get just the average wine ratings from the top of the page, like those circled in red here. 
[average wine ratings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2ov4.png)

As long as this list is always the first one on the page, you can use something like this to get them.

```
list_of_ratings = soup.find("ul", {"class", "wineRatings_list"})('span')
```

Note that the "find" method will just grab the first instance it finds, hence the need for the average rating list to be at the top of the page.

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to grab all the rows in average wine ratings. I think I figured it out with soup.find_all("li", {"class" : "wineRatings_listItem"})